# The entries of diagonal matrix $D$ are only $1$ or $-1$ then $D=D^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, involutions

The entries of diagonal matrix $D$ are only $1$ or $-1$ then $D=D^{-1}$

**My attempt:** First I thought maybe determinant works but it does not because it is not certain that determinant is equal to $1$ or $-1$ and also that gives us nothing about entries for $D^{-1}$.

Intuitively, I can say yes that should be true but I couldn't prove. I ask myself the following how do I find inverse of matrix? One way is using r.r.e.f. Since matrix has only $+1$ and $-1$ then its r.r.e.f should be itself.

Is there any other way to show?

Comment: How about just computing $D^2$? What do you know about the product of two diagonal matrices?

Comment: Very nice! If you have two diagonal matrices then entries of product is just product of entries. Indeed, entries of $A^2$ must be $\ge 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $D=\textrm{diag}(d_1, d_2, \ldots ,d_n) $ and $d_i\neq 0 ,\forall i\in\Bbb{N}_n$ then $D^{-1}=\textrm{diag}(\frac{1}{d_1}, \frac{1}{d_2}, \ldots ,\frac{1}{d_n})$

Hint: Compute $DD^{-1}$

Comment: Note: $D=\textrm{diag}(d_1, d_2, \ldots, d_n) $ and $E=\textrm{diag}(e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_n) $ then $DE=\textrm{diag}(d_1e_1, d_2e_2, \ldots, d_ne_n) =ED$